# What is the difference between ng build and webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

As I understand it, `ng-build` creates a distributable packaged version of your application. I also understand that `webpack` is used to bundle Javascript modules.

I ran `ng build` on a test project and found that it created a `dist` folder containing what looked like a packaged version of my Angular application. All of the `.js` files had been combined however my referenced `.css` files had been left in the original form (not bundled or minified).

Therefore, what is the difference between using `ng build` or `webpack` to do this job. Or are they complimentary? Would I potentially use both in my deployment pipeline?

Comment: As far as I remember ng-cli has now been configured to use webpack for the most recent versions and has been utilised in a way to work with Angular .ts projects. You wont need only one to work with build process. The other installs the dependency internally. Use ng-cli is what I recommend.

Comment: `"webpack": "~2.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.4.0", ` https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but worth to note:

If your css files were not compiled, it probably means, either:

1. you ran `ng build` (a.k.a. `ng build --dev`) which adds `default --extract-css` to `false`:

> --extract-css (aliases: -ec)
>
> Extract css from global styles onto css files instead of js ones.

2. You ran `ng build --prod` but forgot to reference your styles as global styles in angular.cli.json:

   `"styles": [
       "styles.css",
       "assets/styles/test.component.css"
     ],`

Once you do this you will find your css files inlined, however, you will also find them in normal format as well. Cant understand why is that..

Answer (score 0):

Webpack and ng-build do pretty much the same job, which is bundling your modules to be used in a browser environment  For example, the Angular module is a feature, which doesn't support in the browser, and ES 6 modules are not implemented in any browser yet, which is why things need to be bundled.ng build only for angular. we can you webpack any UI related applications including angular.

Comment: Copy and pasting answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466285/1137669 isn't appreciated.