# angular 2 - ng build vs webpack build

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am looking to see what is the best approach to buid and deploy my angular 2 web application?

I finally need to serve it as a web bundle resource to my dropwizard application.

1. I am trying to understand if I should retain ng build and use that to generate my dist folder or should I override that with webpack and carry out whatever is specified in https://angular.io/guide/webpack .
2. Does ng build internally call webpack? if yes, is there any benefit in setting up my own webpack-config file and setting it up as discussed in https://angular.io/guide/webpack .

Comment: are there any reasons that make you want to configurate webpack by yourself?

Comment: No, I was a bit lost becuase I saw a detailed documentation from angular on how to setup webpack based build - https://angular.io/guide/webpack . So I wasn't sure if I could stick with ng build. Or whether webpack based build as above is the right approach to take. Does ng build --env=prod do whats in the above link?

Comment: I cant really say a lot about webpack cause I lack the knowledge, but if you are using angular cli and you dont need to customize the build step, then ng build is a good option

Answer (score 2):

angular cli use webpack in the current version and you can config your builds using this command

```
 ng eject
```

more info here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject with this command your webpack configuration file will appear and you can customnize.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack and ng-build do pretty much the same job, which is bundling your modules to be used in a browser environment  For example, the Angular module is a feature, which doesn't support in the browser, and ES 6 modules are not implemented in any browser yet, which is why things need to be bundled.